# GWT (smartgwt) grid sort selected records top

Tags: sorting, gwt, grid, selection, smartgwt

I have a grid where the user can select records via checkbox in front of every record. Now I have a requirement to sort the records based on their selection, so that all selected records should be placed top, followed by the not selected ones.

Is there any standard function to achieve this? As an alternative I thought of saving the selection state as an attribute on every record and sort based on the attribute.

The code for the column is:

```
gridRealmDt.setSelectionType(SelectionStyle.SIMPLE);
gridRealmDt.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX);
```

I try to describe the code I use as the affected code is deeply nested in our own framework classes.
gridRealmDt is a subclass of smartgwt ListGrid. In my Dialog a create an instance of the grid which creates an instance of a database bound datasource. When the dialog is loaded the records are fetched from the database and after that a registered an dataArrivedHandler where I select the records which match records from another table.

I tried to place the selection attribute in an extra field and use that for sortig before my other sort criteria, but this does not work. Here is the code for the field I am using.

```
ListGridField txtSelected = new ListGridField(SELECTED, "");
txtSelected.setHidden(true);
txtSelected.setSortByDisplayField(true);
txtSelected.setCanSortClientOnly(true);
```

When I do not set the canSortClientOnly property the order by is sent to my database  resulting in an error, as the table does not contain that field, so I set the property. Now I get following error

Removing field from the sort Specifier array because it specifies canSort Client Only: true and all data is not yet client-side.

I also tried to use a sortNormilizer on the Name field which is my main sort criteria, but the normalizer is called before the selection value is set to the record.

```
record.setAttribute(CARealmDS.SELECTED,selected ? "a" : "b");
```

I also cannnot find a way to call the normalizer when selection changes.

Currently we are using Smart GWT Version 6.0p.

Comment: Please provide sample code of the grid and how you are generating the checkbox field. Also, Smartgwt version is useful to see which apis you have access to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any standard function. Just use grid store update. Place checked items first.

Comment: can you give me sample calls for the mentioned functions? thanks